# Запустить bat файл в новой консоли и вернутся сразу не дожидаясь завершения

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Как запустить две консоли одновременно?

У меня есть `.bat` файл в нем команды для запуска сервиса ngrok (`ngrok.exe tcp 4040`).

В моей программе код `os.system('1.bat')` при выполнении открывает консоль ngrok, а моя программа прекращает работу (пока работает ngrok).

Как сделать так, чтобы открывались два окна, моя программа и сервис ngrok?

Comment: related: [How can I open two consoles from a single script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19479504/4279)

Comment: чтобы запустить произвольную программу, не дожидаясь пока запущенный процесс завершится, можно `subprocess.Popen` вместо `os.system` использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А попробуйте через [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) вызвать:

```
os.startfile('1.bat')
```